# VSTS Team Build Mail notification should include the "associateChangeSets"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Team Build Guru's

I am looking for "Associated ChangeSets" list included in the build mail notifications

say, by default we get a build notification like this,

```
Team Project:   Content Server
Build Number:   MerchantPortal_1.0.0707.69
Build Agent:    \Content Server\MerchantPortalBuildBox
Build Definition:   \Content Server\MerchantPortal QA
Build started by:   ENETDOM\jrichter
Build Start Time:   7/7/2009 8:25:30 AM
Build Finish Time:  7/7/2009 8:30:49 AM

Notes: 
- All dates and times are shown in GMT -05:00:00 Central Daylight Time
- You are receiving this notification because of a subscription created by ENETDOM\enbuild
Provided by Microsoft Visual Studio® Team System 2008
```

What I really would like is an email containing the changes. So the user does NOT have to click an URL to retrieve the list of changes. 
So... I would the mail to look something like this instead:

```
Team Project:   Content Server
Build Number:   MerchantPortal_1.0.0707.69
Build Agent:    \Content Server\MerchantPortalBuildBox
Build Definition:   \Content Server\MerchantPortal QA
Build started by:   ENETDOM\enbuild
Build Start Time:   7/7/2009 8:25:30 AM
Build Finish Time:  7/7/2009 8:30:49 AM


**Associated changesets:
482 DOMAIN\johny    Not needed...
486 DOMAIN\adam A final synchronization with SourceSafe files after the 15 december release.
487 DOMAIN\bob  Corrected the naught millenium bug....
488 DOMAIN\sarah    Reverted back to csproj file with SC changes....
Associated  work items:**
....


Notes: 
- All dates and times are shown in GMT -05:00:00 Central Daylight Time
- You are receiving this notification because of a subscription created by ENETDOM\enbuild
Provided by Microsoft Visual Studio® Team System 2008
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration option I know of that allows this.

If you have access to the server, I think there's a way to write custom code which hooks into the event system on the server and you could build your own email format. But it would be a lot of work I think.

I agree it's frustrating that there's no way to customise the email content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the associated changset:

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(TeamFoundationServerUrl);
IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
IBuildDetail build = buildServer.GetAllBuildDetails(new Uri(BuildUri));

List<IChangesetSummary> assocChangesets = InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(build);
```

You can listen builds using web service and read BuildUri from eventXml.